# What are the default MSMQ private queue permissions on Windows 2008 Server

Tags: permissions, msmq

I have installed MSMQ on a publicly hosted standalone Windows 2008 Server (workgroup), already running IIS 7.0 and a number of .NET websites.

I've created a private transactional queue named 'Requests' as per the screen shot below.

[image]

Without changing any permissions or settings, is this private queue available remotely ?  How can I verify who can and can't read/send messages to this queue.

Are there any tools or scripts I can run using PowerShell that are available to attempt to connect to a remote private queue ?

Comment: May be this can help u: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/07/10/getting-msmq-messages-out-of-windows-server-2008.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private queues are queues that are not published in Active Directory and are displayed only on the local computer that contains them.

Read this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776346(v=ws.10).aspx

This means you won't be able to use powershell to acess a remote private queue -  you will have to make that queue public.

Then see this page for details on accessing the queue: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh405007(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: So just to clarify that the private queue I created running on a Windows 2008 server in workgroup mode, can not be accessed remotely, either directly or by Powershell, unless it is exposed using something like a .NET web service to read the local private queue ? In addition, I had to grant IIS_IUSRS both Receive and Send Message access, in order for my .NET web service to have permission to read and write to the queue.  Is this correct ?  Also what about if another website on the same IIS server tried to access the queue ?

Comment: Exactly right - you need a something (like a service) to access it. As for permissions, allowing IIS_IUSRS access means all application pools will have access to the queue.  A better approach would be to change the account under which that application pool is running, and to set the queue permissions appropriately.